# Splitting Document Set properties over separate web parts

Tags: document-library, document-set, document-info-panel

I am currently trying to reconfigure the welcome page on my company's SharePoint so that the document set properties is split over three web part, with different information in each.

There would be a web part for client info, then for accounting info and finally for tasks, with data coming from the columns within the document set itself.

I have searched online and tried to make a solution myself but it doesn't appear to be possible.

Is there a way? Or is there another solution?

Comment: I'm curious to know how many site collections you are working with?  Is this all on one 'root' site and are all the Document Sets saved in a single Document Library?  Or are the Document Sets split across different site collections (e.g. across different departmental sites?)

Comment: I am currently working on one 'secondary' site whilst I make these changes which will be implemented into the root site. I have never worked with SharePoint before and only had limited skills prior to starting work for this company a year ago so I have pretty much learnt on the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what it appears you are asking, if this information is all contained within one library you should be able to create three app part instances and then filter, sort, and group them individually using the modify view functionality to get what you are looking for each one.

Comment: Ideally, it would be the document set properties replicated 3 times but with different parts of the properties displayed in the 3 web parts.

Comment: I think I have found a solution with InfoPath, just trying to find out the correct way to format it